Prisma query: Array of relations
I am using prisma orm into my nestjs project. I need to make a query on the entity users that have into their roles a given list of roles. The relation is m:n. I can make you a basic example: I want all the users that have into their roles the ones with ids 1 and 2. They can also have other roles, but they need to have at least these two.
I tried:
{
  roles: {some: {id: {in: [1, 2]}}}
}

This works, but it gives me the users that have at least one role from the list.
I have also tried with every but it filters only the users that have the exact list of roles.
Here is the model:
model User {
  id              Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  //...  
  roles   Role[]      @relation("Roles")

}

model Role {
  id      Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  //...
  users   User[] @relation("Roles")
}

I am using prisma version 5.11.0

Your question is a bit vague - Do you want every User whose has a Role ID of 1 or 2? Or must it be 1 and 2?

@SheaHunterBelskyit must be 1 AND 2! The list of roles from the client request must be in the list of user's roles present in the DB.

Have you tried using OR to see if the ID is explicitly equal to 1 or 2?
{
  roles: {
    every: {
      OR: [
        {id: {equals: 1} },
        {id: {equals: 2} }
      ]
    } 
  }
}

